# How to replace a specific parenthesis in string python

Tags: python, replace

```
string = "Title (do not change) $(change into curly bracket)title python"
```

I am having trouble with replacing the parenthesis into purely bracket that has $ in the front.
I tried using replace function

```
text_title = static_text_title.replace('$(','${').replace(')','}')
```

but it changed all the closing parenthesis into purely bracket.
So, the output should look like,

```
"Title (do not change) ${change into curly bracket}title python"
```

Comment: Do you know the exact text that will be inside the second set of parentheses?  If so, then this is straightforward: `s = s.replace("$(something)", "{something}")`

Comment: Apparently, no! I only know there will be a $(). The text inside of the parentheses  could be varies.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) here.

```py
string = "Title (do not change) $(change into curly bracket)title python"
pattern = r"\$(\()(.+?)(\))"

out = re.sub(pattern, r"${\2}", string)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
Title (do not change) ${change into curly bracket}title python
```

Check the pattern at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Lj7bwZ/1).

Explanation:

`\$` : match a `$`
`(\()` : 1st capturing group containing one `(`
`(.+?)` : 2st capturing group match anything one or more times but as few as possible (non greedy)
`(\))` : 3rd capturing group containing one `)`

When replacing you replace the match (which is: `$` and group 1,2 and 3) with `$`, the curly brackets and the 2nd group.

Comment: I think this method doesn't work for nested brackets like this one `"Title (do not change) $(change into (problem)curly bracket)title python" ` , the output will be  `Title (do not change) ${change into (not effected}curly bracket)title python`

Comment: @OhadSharet good point. if you remove the `?` in the 2nd capturing group it will work again. (and will fail again if there is a third title at the end which shouldn't be changed....lets wait what the OP says, if he needs that)

Comment: the posted answer worked perfectly fine. Fortunately, I don't think I will be needing the nested brackets. so it works for me. Thank you so much for the help:)